# Class adapter pattern in the classic TimedDoor case study

Tags: adapter, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

In Uncle Bob's classic [tutorial on ISP](https://courses.cs.duke.edu/compsci308/spring23/readings/isp.pdf), he presents a case study on a timed security door. Martin suggests two possible designs for combining the TimerClient with the Door hierarchy:

An Object Adapter pattern:
[image: Object adaper]

A Class Adapter pattern:
[image: Class adapter]

My question is how to interpret the Class Adapter. Who is the adapted interface, who is the adapter and who is the adaptee? There are two options that can I think of:

- The Door is the adaptee, and the TimedDoor is the adapter. This conforms with the structure of the Class Adapter pattern, as the adapter inherits from the two abstract classes.
- The TimedDoor is both the adapter and adaptee. This is consistent with the Object adapter solution, with a "shortcut", combining the adapter and adaptee together.

Can you clarify this point?

Answer (score 0):

The UML diagrams from page 141 of the GoF book include appropriate labels.

[image: GoF page 141]

So your first bullet is closer: the *Target* is whichever interface the *Client* knows and uses; the *Adaptee* is whichever interface gets called by the *Adapter*. If the *Client* knows and uses both interfaces, you can have a two-way Adapter where *Target* and *Adaptee* are interchangeable.